# Chart.js label right y axis where chart hit y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart that has like 8 guidelines, as below:

[image]

I want to mark right y axis with what those guidelines mean. Data points for these guidelines are all static, based on no calculation. And each dataset is identified by a percentage 5%,10%,25%,...

Chart.js provide a way to put labels on right and left y axis as below:

```
yAxes: [{
    id: 'A',
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'left',
    ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: minY,
        max: maxY
  }
},
{
    id: 'B',
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'right',
    ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }
}]
```

which produces following result, but that's not what I want.

[image]

Just wondering if there is a way to achieve what I want.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: It might be possible to do this using a 2nd Y axis like you are thinking.  You will have to make use of some of the `ticks.callback` property.  I can submit an answer showing how to do this but I first wanted to ask how the 5%, 10%, 25%, 50% values are calculated.  Could you update your question with your specific chart.js config + data so I can re-create the exact chart in my answer?

Comment: @Konstantinos I want it to look like the first image in the post.

Comment: @jordanwillis just updated the question. And percentages are not calculated they are just identifier of datasets we are plotting the chart for

Comment: give us the whole chart code (myChart variable) or make a jsfiddle.